# Mailchimp API 2.0 lists/subscribe responding with error 250 List_MergeFieldRequired MMERGE4 is required

Tags: mailchimp

I'm attempting to use the [lists/subscribe](https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/lists/subscribe.php) Mailchimp API 2.0 endpoint to subscribe an email to a list, but I keep getting a puzzling error.  My request looks like:

```
{
    "apikey":"myapikey-us5",
    "id":"listid",
    "email":{"email":"my@email.com"},
    "double_optin":false,
    "send_welcome":true
}
```

I'm sending this to `https://us5.api.mailchimp.com/2.0/lists/subscribe.json` and getting this response:

```
{
    "status": "error",
    "code": 250,
    "name": "List_MergeFieldRequired",
    "error": "MMERGE4 must be provided - Please enter a value"
}
```

And if I specify `"merge_vars": {}` I still get the same error.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means you need to provide a value for MMERGE4 merge field. How you do this depends on what type of merge field MMERGE4 is, but It would be like this:

```
{
    "apikey":"myapikey-us5",
    "id":"listid",
    "email":{"email":"my@email.com"},
    "double_optin":false,
    "send_welcome":true,
    "merge_vars": {
        "MMERGE4": "something"
    }
}
```

But you should look and see what type of data that is, otherwise you might cause issues for whomever set that up as a required field.

Comment: Thanks, I realized soon after that `MERGE4` was a custom field I didn't know about.  Sigh...